# File manager with customizable metadata columns

Tags: linux, file-manager

Do you know if there is on Linux a file manager where one can customize in a simple way the columns in the list view where the metadata is displayed? By this, I mean all the information related to the file in question (e.g. image size and resolution for images, duration for videos, etc). This is typically the information obtainable for exiftool, for example. I tested many file managers until now, but none so far have offered what I am looking for.

Comment: Right there with you. I'm missing all of the Metadata I can Sort, Group, and view in Windows Explorer on Linux, and no FM I use can do it. I got recommended to try Double Commander, a curses/TUI FM, which has some capability to do such with plugins.